# Is there a way to autoclick on R shiny app as soon as we open the app

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to auto click on one of the columns in DT table in shiny
Example
df is datatable that is rendered. df has 10 columns. Once the application opens. I need to auto click on the one of the columns of df. I used `onclick(colnames(df))`. I think this is a wrong approach. But can anyone help me

Comment: What do you mean by click on the columns? Do you intent to get numeric indices of the clicked column? Please post a reproducible example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, you are 100% correct. I need to get numeric indices of the clicked columns.